# Миграция с Windows Server 2000 Server на Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows, active-directory, миграция, windows-server-2012

Вопрос такой на сервере стоит Windows 2000 SP4, необходимо мигрировать на Windows Server 2012. Всего в AD 40 пользователей.Условия миграции:Необходимо переместить учетные записи пользователей и сетевые ресурсы, миграция дескрипторов безопасности (SD), организационных единиц (OU).Чем можно произвести миграцию, есть ли программные средства которые позволили бы это сделать в один клик?

Answer (score 2):

1. [Перенос схемы, GPO, OU, Group в тестовый домен](http://shurfik.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-gpo-ou-group-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81-2/)
2. Используется утилита  LDIFDE позволяет перенести - пользователей, группы, OU

пробовал работает.